# Допустима ли точка перед цитатой в нескольких предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация

Допустима ли точка перед цитированием в нескольких предложениях?

Например:
Первые две строки он прокомментировал так. И дальше идет цитата из книги определенного автора.

То есть:
Первые две строки он прокомментировал так. «Здесь цитата из книги в нескольких предложениях».

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы пишете *"прокомментировал **так**",* то в любом случае напрашивается двоеточие. Точка мне видится только при формулировке такого типа: *Далее приведено...*

Comment: "в любом случае напрашивается двоеточие." Даже если дальше приводится несколько предложений?

Comment: Мне кажется — да. Но это моё видение. Не уверен, что со мной все согласятся. Возможно, я и видел примеры с двоеточием и несколькими предложениями в литературе, а может, и нет. Не помню точно.